# Can we use CSOM inside .NET 5.0

Tags: development, csom, .net

I have created a new .NET 5.0 core console application >> but i am not sure if currently CSOM is supported inside .NET 5.0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [new CSOM library](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/using-csom-for-dotnet-standard) supports .NET Standard 2.0, which means .NET 5 support.

Comment: thanks for the reply. but from where i can get the CSOM library which is supported inside .NET 5?